# Lagrange multipliers - closest point to the origin on a cone

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

> Use the Lagrange method to find the points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ closest to the origins, and which are on the cone $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and also on the plane $x+2y=6$.

We want to minimize the distance from the origin to the point(s) $P$, thus we want to minimize $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, which is equal to minimizing the function $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$. We minimize this subject to the constraints $g(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2-z^2$ and $h(x,y,z) = x+2y-6$.

Using the Lagrange method, we have the following set of equations:

$$\nabla f(x,y,z) = \lambda \nabla g(x,y,z) + \mu \nabla h(x,y,z)  $$

$$\langle 2x,2y,2z \rangle = \lambda \langle 2x,2y,-2z \rangle + \mu \langle 1,2,0 \rangle $$

Solving the system of equations arising from this yields us the points $P = \big(\dfrac{6}{5}, \dfrac{12}{5}, \pm \dfrac{6}{\sqrt{5}})$

I'm wondering if my application of the Lagrange method here is correct.

Comment: Do you mean the plane $z=x+2y-6$?

Comment: You seem to be asking people to check your work; it would help if you showed it.

Comment: @qbert I literally just showed my entire solution to the problem, just wondering if I applied the Lagrange method correctly. The numbers don't matter to me, just the process.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales No, $x+2y=6$, so it's actually a $h(x,y)$, but I thought that for these problems you can just say it's $h(x,y,z)$ with $z$ being 0? Not sure if that's allowed, mathematically.

Comment: @YakSalTafri you literally wrote down the lagrangian equation and then stated the solution to the problem. The hard part of these problems is generally solving the system. If you want to know if you set it up correctly, you may want to ask that

Comment: @YakSalTafri if you have no conditions on z, that does not mean z is automatically 0

Comment: @qbert Maybe to someone who already is very familiar with the method, but for someone like me who is just learning about it, solving the system is the most routine part and setting up the exercise is the most difficult part.

Comment: @YakSalTafri I am not trying to be unkind, I am trying to get you to be specific about your question. Yes, you did apply the formula correctly

Comment: $P_1$ and $P_2$ are not on the plane,  $h(\frac 56, \frac 53, z) = \frac 56+\frac {10}3-6 = -\frac{11}6$

Comment: @DougM I already spotted a mistake, will rectify and post the edit soon.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Yeah, it's supposed to be a line $x+2y=6$, but in the problem it says "on the plane $x+2y=6$". Now I'm very confused myself. I'm making a past paper, so I don't know if they actually made a mistake in their questioning..

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^3$, $x+2y=6$ is a plane parallel to the $z$-axis.

Comment: $x+2y=6$ is a plane.  $z$ is unconstrained.  Your updated answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of two Lagrangian multipliers to solve the problem seems to be entirely sound, and so I have really nothing to add there. But it's worth noting that you can actually get away with just *one* such multiplier!

Since $x^2+y^2=z^2$, we have $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2=2x^2+2y^2$. Then both this objective function and the constraint $g(x,y)=x+2y=6$ depend only $(x,y)$; all that remains is $x^2+y^2=z^2$, which doesn't constrain $x,y$ unless $z$ is known. So we can set aside this equation, and what we have is an optimization problem in $(x,y)$. Introducing a Lagrangian multiplier $\lambda$, we demand that $\nabla f = (4x,4y)=\lambda \nabla g = (\lambda,2\lambda)$. This implies $\lambda = 2y=4x$ and so $(x,y)=(\frac65,\frac{12}5).$ Then $z=\pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\pm\frac{6}{\sqrt{5}}$ and the minimum distance is $\frac{12}{\sqrt{5}}.$